# Shape of output for dynamic_rnn with time_major=True

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I'm using TensorFlow to implement an RNN.  I create the recurrent unit like this:

```
gru_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.GRUCell(16)
zero_state = gru_cell.zero_state(1, tf.float32)
initial_state = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, zero_state.get_shape())
out_tensor, final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
    gru_cell,
    parent_tensor,
    initial_state=initial_state,
    time_major=False)
print(out_tensor.get_shape())
```

It reports the output shape as `(1, ?, 16)`, just as I would expect.  The second dimension is `?` because `max_time` is unknown.

Now I switch it to `time_major=True`.  Based on the documentation, I expect that to just swap the first two axes, so the output shape should be `(?, 1, 16)`.  But it isn't.  Instead it's `(1, 1, 16)`.  What's going on?  `max_time` is still unknown, so why is it hardcoding it to 1?

Answer (score 0):

From Tesnorflow documentation, https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn

[image]

according to above, now your max_time = 1,batch_size =?,input_size= 16

Now according to the documentation,
[image]

your output should be in the shape of (1,?,16).

Comment: But it isn't.  It actually is (1,1,16).  My question is why?